# Symmetrix gatekeepers on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, emc

I have some Solaris machines that are connected to EMC Symmetrix for SAN storage.  Apparently the Symm has a gatekeeper device that is used with the symmetrix CLI.  We don't need the CLI, but I have these gatekeeper devices that constantly fill /var/adm/messages and the like with corrupt label errors.

Is there anything I can do (short of deleting the devices on machine start) to get rid of them?  Or should I just try to get our SAN guy to get the installer for the CLI?  These things are getting annoying, and the devfsadmd daemon keeps rediscovering them on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Warning messages should only be logged in case disk labels are rescanned periodically (eg. format command in cron or other disk activity which will trigger a VTOC scan on the GK disks). If you don't need the GKs, unmask them from the host. Labelling might work temporarily but GK disk contents (including VTOC) can be wiped/changed without your intervention so it'd not be a long term fix.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which syslog facility and level they have, you could filter them out by modifying

```
/etc/syslog.conf
```

to exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question so it's probably already answered but...

You can label them to stop the messages.

You may want the CLI for other reasons, but if you don't, you can also unmap the gatekeepers from the Symmetrix FAs or take them out of the masking database.

Comment: what if the gatekeeper device can't be labeled?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say to check the status of the gatekeepers on the symm... are they read-only or "not ready"?  If that's not it, then I would just unmap them from the FAs.  Their only purpose is for inband Symmetrix CLI commands.  And actually any Symmetrix target LUN can be used for that, including the VCM.  Generally people don't do that, but it's possible.